# Can you upload a new picture to S3 and use the same link?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

For my app I need users to be able to upload their profile pictures.

The way it works is they send their info (name, email...) and their pictures to a lambda function. The Lambda function stores the pictures in S3 and stores the info and the link to the picture in S3 in DynamoDB.

Users should be able to upload a new picture and use it as their profile picture. Would it be possible to **upload a picture that would use the same link in S3** (meaning I would replace the old picture by the new one while keeping the link the same)?

This way I don't have to update any table in dynamoDB. The thing is that I need to use the link in other tables and this would avoid having to update every tables it is in.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the file upload it again with the same key. e.g.

```
aws s3 cp ./hello1.text s3://document/hello.text
```

May receive old data until replication is completed. refer - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#BasicsKeys